# HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect problem with Content-Disposition

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, content-disposition

If you set `AllowAutoRedirect` of `HttpWebRequest` to `true`, then it automatically redirects until it reaches some content. For example on `sourceforge.net` it redirect to mirror and then mirror would return the content in response. Problem is, the final response doesn't contain any `Content-Disposition` header, instead it's prior response has one, which redirect us to the last URL where download begins. If `AllowAutoRedirect` is set to `true` then we miss the file name and if set to false, we should redirect manually and keep an eye out for `Content-Disposition`. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like a broken webapp. Anyhow, I would work around it by doing the redirects manually, instead of being handled by HWR.

Comment: Is there any sample code ? something like a child class of HttpWebClient which overrides the redirection method and keep track of content-disposition.